# MySQL GROUP BY altering with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Database table image]
I have the table above and I want to run a MySQL query to group rows where `noteId`, `dataId`, and `type` have the same value.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userTo = '1' GROUP BY noteId, dataId, type ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Now I believe this query above should do the grouping and return the last row in each group. But instead I am getting the first row in each group.

For example rows `13`, `14` and `16` are grouped together. So I want row `16` to be returned by doing `ORDER BY id DESC` but instead am getting row `13`.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add your php parsing code as well? from the returned rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  table ORDER BY id DESC) t
 WHERE t.userTo = '1' GROUP BY t.noteId, t.dataId, t.type
```